# date_created surviving file upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, mp3, exif

Is there any way to build a file upload system to preserve the date_created of the file being uploaded?

I'm interested in getting the date_created or date_modified of audio recordings in order to match them up with jpegs' EXIF times (which do survive the upload process).

If it's not possible with an html upload form, might a Flash or Java applet-based uploader work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definately cant do this with JavaScript.

You can do it with Flash:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#creationDate

If you have a signed applet, you can get the last modified date in Java (Java doesnt provide access to the creation date, this is an OS level thing)

- http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html
  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()